# Win 10 -> VS 2019 -> .NET Core 3 WPF application -> Publish to directory (self-contained for linux-x64) -> Publish failed

Tags: linux, wpf, deployment, .net-core-3.0, self-contained

Weird issue I've faced today.

Pre-requisites:
Installed:

```
VS2019
.NET Core 3.0
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```
Create new "WPF App (.NET Core)"
To the MainWindow.xaml add single TextBlock:
    <TextBlock Text="WPF on Linux" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
Create new Publish Profile like the following:
```

[image]

```
Then save and publish
```

Expected to see the application being published. But instead the following message pops up:

[image]

And here is the content of the mentioned in the error message file:

```
2019-10-28 19:39:43
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__202.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---

System.Exception: Publishing failed.

===================
```

The question is.. What am I doing wrong and/or how to fix the issue?

Important note:

```
If Deployment Mode is set to "Framework Dependent", and the Target Runtime is "linux-x64" then the project is published into the directory with no issues.
If Deployment Mode is set to "Self-contained", but Target Runtime is "win-x64", then deployment works with no issues.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the build output window:

> There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'linux-x64'

WPF is not supported on Linux, only Windows.

Comment: Do you know if there is some intention to make it work also on linux ? (Like git issue, etc...)

Comment: Here is useful comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4743#issuecomment-634969157

Comment: @TarmoPikaro MAUI is one option for cross platform .NET apps, but for some reason Microsoft is leaving the Linux support up to the community. There is also Uni and Avalonia. I have used Avalonia to write desktops apps for Linux and it is good.